# While trying get the color of the dot from web page I am getting error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, javascriptexecutor

The Error I am getting is Below:
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException:javascript error:Failed to execute'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'
I am trying to find the element and get the color of it and the element is stored in DOM with ::before
I am not getting this element color by using xpath for span please suggest what wrong with this code

```
String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.dot[_ngcontentephc8]'),':before').getPropertyValue('background')";
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)Browser.getDriver();
String colorCode = (String) jse.executeScript(script);
System.out.println("colorCode);
String hexColorCode = convertBackgroundColorToHexFormat(colorCode);
System.out.println("hexColorCode);
return hexColorCode.equalsIgnoreCase(color);
```

Comment: Can you add to the question the relevant part of HTML for the element you are trying to get? The part with the square brackets `[_ngcontentephc8]` doesn't seem valid to me

Comment: <span class="classname"> ::before <span/> --this is the element I am trying to get using javascriptexecuter

Comment: `.dot[_ngcontentephc8]` means: select element with class "dot" and attribute "_ngcontentephc8". This doesn't seem to correspond to what you are trying to get, so the result is null, and `getComputedStyle` throws an error as expected..

Comment: could you help how can i resolve the issue

Comment: Are you sure this is the element rendered on your browser? The part `class="classname"` seems weird to me. Does it appear like this when you inspect it in your browser?

Comment: Yes it appears like this in span tag and in <span> ::before <span/>. the before is showing the correct element but i am not able to locate that using xpath or jse

Comment: The will looks like this and I want locate the ::before element --->                                                                                         
  <mat-cell _ngcontent-cah-c8 class="mat-cell cdk-column-status mat-column-status ng-star-inserted" role="grid cell">flex
<span _ngcontent-cah-c8 class="dot dot-green">
::before
</span>

Comment: Does it work with `'.dot[_ngcontent-cah-c8]'` then?

Comment: Actually no its not working with that script above mentioned